# Pegar nomes de arquivos e colocar em array char

Tags: c, c++, array-multidimensional

Como que pego os nomes dos arquivos de um diretório e coloco num array multidimensional de char?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main()
{
    char arrayNomes[10][50];
    char dirn[50];
    DIR *dir = NULL;
    struct dirent *drnt = NULL;

    dir = opendir(dirn);
    if (dir)
    {
        while (drnt = readdir(dir))
        {
            printf("%s\n", drnt->d_name);
            //Como fazer algo como isso abaixo:
            for (...)
            {
                arrayNomes[i] = drnt->d_name;
            }
        }
        closedir(dir);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Can not open directory '%s'\n", dirn);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Primeiro precisa decidir se vai fazer em C ou C++, parece C, certo? Qual o problema que está tendo?

Comment: c++, mas o código acima é apenas c. Problema: Não sei converter "drnt->d_name" para um array de char multidimensional. Na verdade nem sei que tipo é "drnt->d_name" e nem sei como saber o tipo dessa variável. "drnt" é uma struct e "d_name" é o que? um array de char?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A estrutura `dirent` é [definida](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Directory-Entries.html) em [`dirent.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/dirent.h.html) como

```
struct dirent
{
    long            d_ino;      /* Sempre zero. */
    unsigned short  d_reclen;       /* Sempre sizeof struct dirent. */
    unsigned short  d_namlen;       /* Tamanho do nome em d_name. */
    unsigned        d_type;     /* Atributos to arquivo. */
    char            d_name[FILENAME_MAX]; /* Nome do arquivo. */
};
```

Como `dirent.d_name` é um array de char, você pode fazer assim

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>

#define MAX_ARRAY_NOMES  10
#define MAX_NOME_ARQUIVO 255

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    char arrayNomes[MAX_ARRAY_NOMES][MAX_NOME_ARQUIVO];
    char dirn[] = { "diretorio_exemplo" };
    DIR *dir = NULL;
    struct dirent *drnt = NULL;

    dir = opendir(dirn);
    if (dir)
    {
        while (drnt = readdir(dir))
        {
            strcpy(arrayNomes[i++], drnt->d_name);
            if (i == MAX_ARRAY_NOMES)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        closedir(dir);

        for (i = 0; i < MAX_ARRAY_NOMES; i++)
        {
            printf("[%d]: %s\n", i, arrayNomes[i]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Can not open directory '%s'\n", dirn);
    }

    return 0;
}
```